# How to disambiguate between traits with the same name?

Tags: rust, substrate, parity-io

I am trying to use both the Assets module and Balances module in my runtime. They both export the Trait `T::Balance`. When I bring the Assets module in scope of my trait like so:

```
pub trait Trait: assets::Trait + balances::Trait {}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0221]: ambiguous associated type `Balance` in bounds of `T`
   --> /home/volt/workspaces/lsaether/vyzer/runtime/src/markets.rs:124:42
    |
124 |         ValidityBond get(validity_bond): T::Balance;
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type `Balance`
    |
note: associated type `T` could derive from `srml_assets::Trait`
   --> /home/volt/workspaces/lsaether/vyzer/runtime/src/markets.rs:124:42
    |
124 |         ValidityBond get(validity_bond): T::Balance;
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
note: associated type `T` could derive from `srml_balances::Trait`
   --> /home/volt/workspaces/lsaether/vyzer/runtime/src/markets.rs:124:42
    |
124 |         ValidityBond get(validity_bond): T::Balance;
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `substrate`, would you be interested in a dedicated Stack Exchange Q&A site for Substrate, Polkadot, et al. -- check out the [Area51 Substrate Proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122626/substrate?referrer=NTUwMTkxYjJjOTJiNjE0YzMxYjgwMGNkZmFlYzdhZTczYjk1ZWY3ZGI4NzJmODUwN2RlYTQ2MTNjZTdkOTZhMAzuL-zybtPN9CHzwE-WUdvBC8WxvPG46b4ayadke6kG0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use `T::Balance` here, you need to be more specific for the Rust compiler.

You can do `<T as balances::Trait>::Balance` or `<T as assets::Trait>::Balance` to specify which "Balance" you actually want to use.

Let me know if this helps!